# Trying to calculate percents with java

Tags: java

So I'm trying to create a java program that will produce 20 random activities of a student. And then calculate the percentage that they are doing that. For example:

> sleeping 40% of the time
>   walking 30% of the time
>   in class 30% of the time

But my percents keep coming off as 0% for three option but 5% for only one.

app.java

```
public class app {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String initName = "John";
        String lastName = "Smith";
        int age = 20;

        double stcount = 0;
        double slcount = 0;
        double clcount = 0;
        double wkcount = 0;

        student st1 = new student(initName, lastName, age);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++);
        {
            String activity = st1.whatsUp1();
            System.out.print(1 + " ");
            System.out.println(st1.whatsUp1());

            if (activity.equals(" studying")) {
                stcount++;
            }

            if (activity.equals(" sleeping")) {
                slcount++;
            }

            if (activity.equals(" in class")) {
                clcount++;
            }

            if (activity.equals(" walking")) {
                wkcount++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(stcount++ / 20 * 100 + "% " + "of the time the student is studying");
        System.out.println(slcount++ / 20 * 100 + "% " + "of the time the student is reading");
        System.out.println(clcount++ / 20 * 100 + "% " + "of the time the student is walking");
        System.out.println(wkcount++ / 20 * 100 + "% " + "of the time the student is in class");
    }
}
```

And then 
student.java

```
public class student {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String[] whatsUp = {" studying", " sleeping", " in class", " walking"};
    int age;

    student(String myFirstName, String myLastName, int myAge) {
        firstName = myFirstName;
        lastName = myLastName;
        age = myAge;
    }

    String getName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    // --------METHODS---------
    String getInfo() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " is";
    }

    String whatsUp1() {
        double rn = Math.random();
        double rn_max5 = rn * 4;
        int ri_max5 = (int) rn_max5;
        return whatsUp[ri_max5];
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `System.out.println(st1.whatsUp1());` will generally produce different results than what is actually stored in activity as whatsUp1() always produces some random result...

Comment: why do you increment `stcount`, etc., in the println. The incremented value is never used as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is in this line

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++);
```

for, if, else, while lines should never be ended with a ";" (semicolon) because then your for-loop will count from 1 to 20 but don't execute the following `{}` statement  and it's substatements.

for example:

```
   for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++); {
       System.out.println("ouch");
   }
```

This code looks like it prints ouch 20 times, but in fact it only does once, because it is equivalent to simply:

```
   for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
   };

   {
       System.out.println("ouch");
   }
```

And yes you can put `{}` anywhere to wrap a statement, it just rarely makes sense, that's why compiler isn't bothering you with an compile-time-error. The code would still be executed (exactly) once, making for a time consuming bug for people not too familiar with the exact java syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in these lines:

```
System.out.println(stcount++/20 * 100 + "% "+ "of the time the student is studying");
```

The culprit is integer division: stcount is an integer which you divide by 20 which is also an integer. Java will then produce a variable which is also an integer. It does this by stripping away the decimal part, eg. if stcount was 10 then it would do 10/20 = 0.5 which would become 0! You need to make sure it doesn't become an integer by using float division, which is done by simply making sure one of the two is a float: `stcount++/20.0`

Comment: double test = 0;
        test++;
        System.out.println(test++/20*100);

Comment: This is completely wrong, java uses the biggest type for every pairwise calculation from left to right, which means that the whole calculation is in double, as long as stcount is the leftmost member. The above programm snippet proves that because it outputs 5.0

Comment: You're right, stcount is double. The ++ put me off guard. So what is the problem then?

Comment: the semicolon after the for loop

Comment: Good eye! *gets upgrade for silly syntax mistake detector*

Comment: to be honest, I copied it into eclipse and let the autoformat do the work for me

Answer (score -2):

Either put a .0 at the end of integer 20 OR append a 'd' to the end of it.

You have this

```
System.out.println(stcount++/20 * 100 + "% "+ "of the time the student is studying");
```

You shoud have either

```
System.out.println(stcount++/20.0 * 100 + "% "+ "of the time the student is studying");
```

OR

```
System.out.println(stcount++/20d * 100 + "% "+ "of the time the student is studying");
```

Comment: Why should OP do that? Where do you see the advantage?